# Is Juvia a Water Dragon Slayer?

Tags: fairy-tail

Is it possible for Juvia to be a Water Dragon Slayer to be in Fairy Tail?

It's honestly making me feel like it and it's now a theory I'm asking myself now if Juvia could be a Water Dragon Slayer?

Comment: no, till the end the premises if to have 7 dragon slayer in FT side and they are Natsu, Gajeel, Wendy, Laxus, Cobra, Sting and Rogue

Answer (score 4):

No, she's not a water dragon slayer. Here is why:

- She never "eats" her element to power up, she only drinks water like normal people.
- Not from any generation of Dragon Slayers:

  - Not a first generation Dragon Slayer. She has never learn her Magic from an actual Dragon.
  - Not a second generation Dragon Slayer. She has never had Dragon Lacrima implanted into her body.
  - Not a third generation Dragon Slayer. She has never both learn her Magic from an actual Dragon and had Dragon Lacrima implanted into her body.
  - Not a fourth generation Dragon Slayer. Not an artificial beings created from Dragon Lacrima. (From the movie)
- None of her skill something like "Roaring Magic".
- None of her magic use the word "Dragon" unlike all Dragon Slayers.
- Never has seen to have motion sickness like Natsu.
- Never has seen to have dragon scales.
- When fighting Dragons, her magic didn't have any effect on them. (the only magic that can hurt dragon is Dragon Slayer magic).
- Like I said in the comment, the premises is to have 7 dragon slayers in FT side and they are Natsu, Gajeel, Wendy, Laxus, Cobra, Sting and Rogue. There's no chance of an 8th Dragon Slayer.